# Why curve_fit and OLS gives different R2?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, statsmodels, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a linear regression model that passes through the origin. I have tried using the curve_fit function from SciPy and the ols function from Statsmodels to achieve this, but they give different R2 scores despite having the same parameters. I am wondering why this is the case and which approach would be best for fitting a linear regression model that passes through the origin. Below is the code I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# create sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2 + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=100)

# fit linear model with no intercept using statsmodels
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
model = smf.ols('y ~ x + 0', data=data)
results = model.fit()
r2_sm = results.rsquared

# fit linear model with no intercept using curve_fit
def lin_func(A, x):
    return A*x

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lin_func, x, y)
y_fit = lin_func(x, *popt)
r2_scipy = r2_score(y, y_fit)

print("R-squared (statsmodels):", r2_sm)
print("R-squared (curve_fit):", r2_scipy)
```